# How to add text next to an image and right below it. All text must be to the right of the picutre

Tags: html

I'm fairly new to HTML and I've been developing a website for a Frat I basically want to have a logo and some text next to it. I'm having issue with the "Gamma Nu Chapter", how can I add it so it can look like this image here.[image: Frat Logo]

This is my code:

```
<div>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">
                <img id="logo" src="{% static 'images/SigmaNuLogo.jpg' %}" alt="">
                Sigma Nu @ University of Michigan
                <p>Gamma Nu Chapter</p>
            </a>
</div>
```

The Gamma Nu Chapter part appears at the bottom of the logo and the first text line. I want it to appear just below the Sigma Nu part like in the picture

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wrap your text in a div like this:

```
<div>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">
            <img id="logo" src="{% static 'images/SigmaNuLogo.jpg' %}" alt="">
            <div>
                Sigma Nu @ University of Michigan
                <p>Gamma Nu Chapter</p>
            </div>
        </a>
</div>
```

And then apply some CSS to make the image and div display side by side.

Something like `.navbar-brand { display: flex; }`